# Spring MVC cannot load .jsp files but returns 404 error

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm studying Spring MVC from a pluralsight course (building web app with spring mvc) with its exercise files. By using the original project, I found that my project cannot load the .jsp files in the resource directory. The prefix and suffix have been setup in bankAppContext.xml, but the project can never load the proper .jsp file.

For curiosity, I created a new file "index.html" right under this project. It turned out that when I started my local Tomcat server, it loaded this "index.html" as home page regardless of the prefix and suffix settings as I intended to load the .jsp files. If I don't have this "index.html", the home page returns "404 Not Found - The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists." Same 404 error to other endpoints such as "/new".

My Intellij Ultimate version is 2019.1.2, Java 1.8.0-191, Tomcat 7.0.94. I'm attaching my screen shots and codes as well.

AccountController.java

```
package com.ps.springmvc.psbankapp.controllers;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.ps.springmvc.psbankapp.model.Account;

@Controller
public class AccountController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showHomePage() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/new")
    public String newAccount() {
        return "newAccount";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/showAccount")
    public String showAccount() {
        return "showAccount";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/saveAccount",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveAccount(Model model,HttpServletRequest request) {
        String acNo = request.getParameter("accountNo");
        String customerName = request.getParameter("accountHolderName");
        String balance = request.getParameter("balance");

        /*model.addAttribute("accountNumber", acNo);
        model.addAttribute("accountHolderName", customerName);
        model.addAttribute("balance", balance); */

        Account account = new Account();
        account.setAccountNo(Integer.parseInt(acNo));
        account.setAccountHolderName(customerName);
        account.setBalance(Integer.parseInt(balance));

        model.addAttribute("account",account);
        return "showAccount";
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>PSBankApp</display-name>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/bankAppContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

bankAppContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ps.springmvc.psbankapp"></context:component-scan>

    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/Views/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

[image]

[image]

Here is my startup logs, which started "index.html" as my home page.

```
C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.94\bin\catalina.bat run
[2019-06-05 08:02:16,201] Artifact PSBankApp: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\xtynd\.IntelliJIdea2019.1\system\tomcat\Unnamed_PSBankApp"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.94"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.94\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.94\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.94\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.94
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Apr 10 2019 16:56:40 UTC
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.94.0
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_191-b12
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\xtynd\.IntelliJIdea2019.1\system\tomcat\Unnamed_PSBankApp
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.94
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\xtynd\.IntelliJIdea2019.1\system\tomcat\Unnamed_PSBankApp\conf\logging.properties
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=C:\Users\xtynd\.IntelliJIdea2019.1\system\tomcat\Unnamed_PSBankApp\jmxremote.password
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=C:\Users\xtynd\.IntelliJIdea2019.1\system\tomcat\Unnamed_PSBankApp\jmxremote.access
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\xtynd\.IntelliJIdea2019.1\system\tomcat\Unnamed_PSBankApp
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.94
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.94\temp
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sennheiser\SoftphoneSDK\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Enterprise Vault\EVClient\x64\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Python36\;C:\Users\xtynd\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\xtynd\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;%SCALA_HOME%\bin;%CYGWIN_HOME%\bin;C:\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-4.0.6\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin;C:\instantclient_11_2;C:\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Python37-32\;C:\Users\xtynd\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Program Files\Fiddler;C:\tools\Cmder;;.
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 547 ms
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.94
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 52 ms
Connected to server
[2019-06-05 08:02:18,316] Artifact PSBankApp: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2019-06-05 08:02:18,645] Artifact PSBankApp: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2019-06-05 08:02:18,645] Artifact PSBankApp: Deploy took 329 milliseconds
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.94\webapps\manager
Jun 05, 2019 8:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.94\webapps\manager has finished in 91 ms
```

Comment: Hello @D Emma - Can you please add your application startup logs as well ?

Comment: The error may indicate that it cannot find the controller endpoints rather than the actual JSP files. it is unclear from the information posted however where the error lies. Set the logging level to debug and you should see detailed info on paths mapped on start-up plus additional info when requests are made.

Comment: @Rohit Thanks for your reply. I just updated my question with the entire startup logs.